# GWT link to JSP page fails when deployed to App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, gwt, hyperlink

I have been linking my GWT app to a page written with JSP, for multifile uploading.

The  gwt code to open the  upload page in a new tab is:

```
Window.open("/secure/newuploads", "_blank", "");
```

This works fine in dev mode but I deployed to App Engine today and
the link doesn't work: the displayed page is blank, no error code.

My JSP and JS files are located in `\war`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try using GWT built in http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FileUpload.html or https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared if the redirect servlet uses 
HttpServlet.doPost() & doGet() not service()
In dev mode I was calling service()
with tests
if(req.getMethod()=="GET")
or
if(req.getMethod()=="POST")

On google's servers these don't work:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming layout of war is like

```
-> webapps
 -> sample
  -> gwtsample
  -> jsp
  -> images
  -> css
```

You should use [GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getHostPageBaseURL%28%29) to get to the root of the sample app and then move to relative jsp file. Reference image below to distinguish between **module base url** and **hostpage url**.

[image]

Comment: This works in dev mode but blank still when deployed:Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+ "secure/newuploads", "_blank", "");

Comment: Can you verify if any error is shown in console? Use firebug or chrome dev tool console.

Comment: no errors shown. Please check my summary of tests I ran today, on this page. There is a  RedirectUser HttpServlet in the jsp code, its probably something to do with this,
req.getRequestDispatcher("/newuploads.jsp");
I really need a gwt multifile upload project that can be used out of the box, but the 3 projects i found are problematic:
1) GWTUpload: huge, lots of missing & irrelevant libs, 
2) upload4gwt: author says its incomplete (looks like its doing some something? very slowly) 
3) joscarsson-gwt-gaemultiupload-example: I can't locate the uploaded blobs

Comment: Are you sure you cannot use gwt-upload as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033304/upload-multiple-files-at-once-using-gwt

Comment: I decided not to proceed with gwt-upload sample as its too big, too many unresolved dependencies. Not worth spending more than 2 hours on such given absence of good reviews. Today I found http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-uploader/ worth a couple of hours investigation.

Comment: Some progress with moxieapps/gwt-uploader: it calls a basic servlet ok but it doesn't use blobstore. I am trying to adapt it to use URL from BlobstoreService.createUploadUrl(URLstring). Do you know blobstore/ gwt well ?

Comment: Sorry. Never came across multi-upload or blob-store in our app. We have example of single file upload using native gwt.

Comment: THIS WORKS IN DEV MODE AND DEPLOYED Window.open(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "newuploads.jsp", "_blank", ""); I never needed .jsp for dev mode, but need it when deployed (?). Also /secure/newuploads  ?? /secure screws it up now. I have no idea what /secure is for.

Comment: :) Well you might have to go to the dev who tried some security related trial code.

Answer (score -1):

You have to give the full path there. Change to:

```
 Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "secure/newuploads", "_blank", "");
```

Go through once :[Getting URL's of my page ,API.](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html)

For more description about the issue you are facing refer this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286204/gwt-getmodulebaseurl-returns-an-incorrect-value) too.

Comment: I tried  Window.open(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "/secure/newuploads", "_blank", ""); This gives 404 in dev mode but deployed gets the html but red 404 message : Sorry the page you were requesting is not found on the server. I guess this is jsp related. I really want to scrap this jsp but I can't find a gwt multifile upload sample that works. Surprising that App Engine development server doesn't simulate properly here.

Comment: Your mapping to the servlet should be like appname/secure/newuploads

Comment: @timmacp Try gwtupload a third party library that makes it easier for multiple file uploads - https://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/

Comment: @SSR I tried GWTUpload in january, couldn't get it to compile, maybe I'll have to try again

Comment: @Baadshah  the mapping is 
<servlet-name>RedirectUser</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.timmacp.server.JSserver.RedirectUser</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RedirectUser</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: I  tested basic URL vs GWT.getModuleBaseURL() vs  GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()
with leading / in the URL vs none, for  3 web.xml mappings:  
/secure/*  
/appname/secure/*
appname/secure/* 
None of them work properly when deployed, and most of them screw up dev mode.
The choices are 
1) basic URL, is good for dev mode but page is blank when deployed 
2) add GWT.getModuleBaseURL(),  or GWT.getHostPageBaseURL(), gives 404 in  dev mode,  but a slight improvement when deployed,ie the basic html shows up but not the uploader.
chrome dev tools /javascript console show no errors